# Options method not allowed, CORS to Google Drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, google-docs

I've created a script for a google drive which posts to [this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ritvl-tH953rPJHfxveF4k7b4mbO_AelPzXgVbfaOKA/edit?usp=sharing).

I invoke it with

```
var request = $.ajax({
            url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbypnRet5l6gUmoGE8oZV2_6da7fImNU12ejHCHCdOambH7UM2CP/exec",
            data: serializedData,
            type: "POST",
            timeout: 10000,
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true
        });
```

which works from [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wqxsz1b/5/).

However, when I implement the exact same code into my local project, it doesn't work. I receive

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbypnRet5l6gUmoGE8oZV2_6da7fImNU12ejHCHCdOambH7UM2CP/exec.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

405 is "Method not allowed", and when I inspect the network traffic I see that for my local request the method is

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
```

However, for the one in jsFiddle it is post as expected. I've done some research, and it seems as if options is a preflight request when doing cross origin, and I can't make it use post directly.

The non-working OPTIONS request has has the following headers that aren't in the working Fiddle's request:

```
access-control-request-headers:accept, content-type
access-control-request-method:POST
```

If I post the same request to my server (instead of to Google), I see it contains the request header `Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8`.

How does jsFiddle get through, when the options method is not allowed? Can I somehow make it skip options and go straight to post?

Comment: Doing this before sending request works?
$.support.cors = true;

Comment: Makes no difference, as far as I can see. Still receive the same error.

Comment: Would you try about running this without port :3000? Meanwhile I am thinking of some solutions

Comment: I can't really run the server locally without specifying a port number. I did however try to deploy it to a test environment without a port number in the url, and received the same error. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preflight OPTIONS requests occur when the request is non-simple, either caused by a non-simple header or a non-simple HTTP method.

The `access-control-request-headers: accept, content-type` header means that you are attempting to send non-simple headers. `Accept` is always simple, but `Content-Type` is only simple when it has the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`. It must be the case that your code (for whatever reason) is trying to use a non-simple value for `Content-Type`, and Google is not providing an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header to allow it.

Instead, you must specify a simple value for `Content-Type`. You can do this by adding an explicit `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` property to your $.ajax options object.